# Equalizer is not showing on Lumia 525

Tags: lumia, settings, audio

I just updated the audio settings on my Lumia 525. When I go to Settings, the description mentions equalizer:

[image]

However, when I open audio settings, there's no equalizer there:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: actually nokia 520 and 525 both does not have hardware requirement for this update , and also u can't uninstall this update. so leave it nothing can be done over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nokia's budget Lumia models (specifically, the 520, 521, 525, 526, 630 and 635) do not support audio equaliser.

Source: [Nokia Support](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/support/product/lumia520/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA141450)